# Video stops buffering and stops playing after few seconds

Tags: flash, video, swfobject

I have some videos on my [webpage](http://www.webstar.ch/de/index.html?sess_shoptype=TW).
They are rendering using swfobject.
The problem is when I start to play one of the video - it only plays till the video has been buffered initially and stops (at the moment on 22 second for the first video).
The same things happens when I opening this video directly by [link](http://www.webstar.ch//templates/videos/mywebstar1_de.mp4)

The most incredible thing is if I logged in by ssh on server and execute simple command:

```
cp videos/mywebstar1_de.mp4 videos_bak/mywebstar1_de.mp4
```

it fix issue (video continue buffering and will play fine), but awhile - some hours.
I haven't ideas what can it be. Please help.
Anton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately I didn't find better solution than following string in crontab:

- - - - - USER touch FULL_PATH/videos/*.mp4

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a problem on the webserver. I tried downloading the file and download slows down past 2 mb.. to 6.7KB/s. Try hosting it on different server .. (dropbox perhaps?).

Comment: It really looks like a problem with webserver. But what exactly causing the problem? Probably something apache settings or not enough memory. Why video works fine if we simple create copy?

Comment: Try installing H264 Streaming Module for Apache. Refer to this: http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki/Mod-H264-Streaming-Apache-Version2